# What do these pronouns stand for?

Tags: pronouns

> With the advance of science, there has been a tendency to slip
> into scientism, and assume that any factual claim can be authenticated if and only if the term ‘scientific’ can correctly be ascribed to **it**. The consequence is that
> non-scientific approaches to reality ― and **that** can include all the arts, religion, and personal, emotional and value-laden ways of encountering the world ― may become labelled as merely
> subjective, and therefore of little account in terms of describing the way the world is.

Q1. In the above passage, what does "it" indicate? Is that  "factual claim"? Am I right?

Q2. Shouldn't "that" be changed to "those"? I think the "that" is supposed to mean "non-scientific approach**es** to reality" and "**approaches**" are plural form. So the plural form of pronoun, "**those**" is needed here. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: "it" refers to "any factual claim"

Comment: How about Q2? "that" or "those"? Thank you for your answer

Comment: I believe "that" refers to a/the category/group of "non-scientific approaches to reality"

Comment: So does the sentence sound okay to native speakers? The "that" doesn't need to be changed to "those"?

Comment: let's wait for native speakers to sort it out :) I am fine with any of that/those/these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that "it" refers to "any factual claim".

I am also wondering why "that" feels more natural than "those" to this English native, because "those" definitely looks more correct.

I believe it is because "that" applies to what is *tacitly understood as* "the collection of non-scientific approaches".

Yes, while "those" is technically more correct, I would not have noticed this unless it had been pointed out to me.